# link_to redirects me to index action and not to the :action one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my redmine plugin view, I've got this link:

```
<%= link_to "Add", :controller => "important_user", :action => "u_edit", :u_id => user.id, :p_id => @project.id, :method => :post %>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :important_user do 
    collection do 
      post :u_edit
    end
  end
```

and controller:

```
class ImportantUserController < ApplicationController
  def u_edit
    puts 'edit!'
  end

  def index
    puts 'ciao'
    puts params[:p_id] 
    puts params[:u_id]
  end
end
```

In spite of calling the expected `u_edit` action, clicking on the link calls the `index` method (I created in a second moment to avoid the `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for ImportantUserController)` error). I've also tried using this sort of link:

```
<%= link_to 'Add', { :action => 'create', :u_id => user.id, :p_id => @project.id}, :method => :post %>
```

But it didn't work either, returning a `projects?p_id=1&u_id=1` GET 404. How could I make it call the desired `u_edit` action?

Comment: Hmmm, can you show more of your routes? also, read the rails guide on routing https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, using named routes is usually a better practice and double check you have rails-ujs on your javascript/application.js file (`a` tags are always GET requests, rails uses rails-ujs to make POST requests)

Comment: firstly you should follow naming conventions for the controllers and can you show route for that method?

Comment: You can use **rake routes | grep u_edit** and then just check the routes and add that route as a path with ids(user.id, @project.id) in link_to.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Visai and Code_aks, this is the output  for `$ rake routes RAILS_ENV="production" | grep u_edit`: `u_edit_important_user_index POST               /important_user/u_edit(.:format)    impportant_user#u_edit`. arieljoud, my routes.rb contains only that snippet, no named routes. Unfortunately, I've got no rails-ujs in public/javascript/application.js, i'm just using vanilla HTML but redmine supports jquery 1.11 IIRC.